# How to add a double with a variable only using one double

Tags: java, double

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Insert value for year (Ez = 2014): ");

    double year = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Insert value for day (Ex = 12): ");

    double day = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Insert number for month (Ex = 3): ");

    double month = in.nextDouble();
    double totalDays = day;

    if (month == 1) {
    } else if (month == 2) { 
        double totalDays = (totalday + 31);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to take the `totalDays` double and use it in the if statement. I want to add it with a variable without using anymore doubles. How?

Comment: what do you mean I want to add it with a variable without using anymore doubles?

Comment: Is any ``double`` necessary in the first place here? ``int`` seems like a better option

Comment: Why 0 days for month1? And why 31 days for month? Maybe 28?

Comment: It's a program to find the day in the year, so if it's Feb 20th, it's day (20) + 31

Answer (score 1):

Your code incorrectly re-declares totalDays inside the conditional. Re-declaring variables in the inner scope is not what you want to do, though. You should use the same variable. Use a compound add-assign operator, like this:

```
totalDays += 31;
```

Comment: Yes , she's probably getting a compile error for duplicate local variable totalDays, and needs to remove the "double" inside the if.

Comment: I'm trying to make it so I can call this calculation in another if statement, but I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: @CloteLewis To share a calculation to be used in multiple places, write a new method for it. Put the code that does computations into the method, and return the result of the calculation in a return statement. Then call the method, passing it the parameters that you want, and store the result in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to avoid repeating writing totalDays = totalDays + 31 in every month, then you need a function.

For the function and main both to see totalDays, it needs to be a member variable declared outside of main, not a local to the main function.

Since you are writing in main which is a static function, totalDays also needs to be static.

public class getSystemInfo
{

```
static double totalDays = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Insert value for year (Ez = 2014): ");

    double year = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Insert value for day (Ex = 12): ");

    double day = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Insert number for month (Ex = 3): ");

    double month = in.nextDouble();
    totalDays = day;

    if (month == 1) {       
    } else if (month == 2) { 
        addThirtyOne();
    }

}

 static void addThirtyOne()
    {
      totalDays = totalDays + 31;
    }
```

}